# Prove that textbook RSA is susceptible to a chosen ciphertext attack

Tags: rsa, number-theory

Given a ciphertext $y$, describe how to choose a ciphertext $\hat{y} \neq y$, such that knowledge of the plaintext $\hat{x}=d_K(\hat{y})$ allows $x=d_k(y)$ to be computed.

So I use the fact that the decryption function is multiplicative: $d_K(y_1)d_K(y_2)= d_K(y_1y_2)$.

Thus we have $d_k(y\hat{y})=x\hat{x}$.

Now if $y\in \mathbb{Z}_n$ is a unit then we set $\hat{y}=y^{-1}$ and thus $x\hat{x}=1$ implying that $x=(\hat{x})^{-1}$

And if $y\in\mathbb{Z}_n$ is a zero divisor then we choose $\hat{y}$ such that $y\hat{y}=0$ and thus $x$ is the zero divisor associated to $\hat{x}$.

Is this correct?

Comment: Only _textbook_ RSA is susceptible to chosen ciphertext attack; [RSA as actually used](http://www.rsa.com/rsalabs/pkcs/files/h11300-wp-pkcs-1v2-2-rsa-cryptography-standard.pdf) is not. Your technique works at least in the first branch where $\gcd(N,y)=1$, though you should clarify that the adversary submits $\hat y$ for decryption, thus obtains $\hat x$, then deduces $x$; and there are other options to the attacker giving a much wider choice of $\hat y$, using knowledge of $e$. For other cases, I duno what "the zero divisor associated to $\hat x$" is, and there are attacks requiring no query.

Comment: Cross posted? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/367739/prove-that-rsa-is-susceptible-to-a-chosen-ciphertext-attack Different user, but same question.

Comment: @mikeazo: It is indeed the same user, as shown by following the link [pajamas](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/users/4207/pajamas), then [_mathematics_](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/26920/), which leads to the other identity. The question is fine, only worded in more mathematical than cryptographic terms, and a bit obviously basic homework or exercise, but showing some effort.

Answer (score 2):

You can choose a random number r, and let $\hat{y}=y\cdot r^e \mod n$. Then, invoke the decryption query on the ciphertext $\hat{y}$ and suppose that the answer is $x'$. Then, you can extract $x=x/r\mod n$.